# Gradle 5 jar.destinationDirectory

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle 5.4.1,

```
File file = new File(jar.destinationDirectory.get().asFile, "foo.txt");
```

Is this the way to convert jar.destinationDirectory to java.io.File? Looks complicated. jar.destinationDir (String) is deprecated.